# LaTeX Tikz Arrows overlays node's labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, nodes, labels

Could you help me to solve this problem, please ? 
Where "Kalman filter" is the label of the node below 
I want the arrows like in red ones.
Thank you in advanced.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,fill=white,ellipse,minimum height=5cm,minimum width=5cm,text width = 2cm,align=center,label=above:\textbf{State-space model}] (A)
  {Transition \\
  abc abc \\
  $ \downarrow $ \\
  Measurement\\
  $y_t  = \hat{t}$ };
\node[xshift=8cm,draw,fill=white,ellipse,minimum height=5cm,minimum width=5cm,text width=2cm,align=center,label=above:\textbf{Estimated data Empirical data}] (B)
  {$ y \rightarrow \emptyset $ \\
  \vspace{5mm}
  $ y_{t / t-1} \rightarrow y_t $};
\node[xshift=4cm,yshift=-5cm,draw,fill=white,ellipse,text width=4cm,align=center,label=above:\textbf{Kalman filter}] (C)
  {$ v_t = y_t - y_{t,t-1} $};
\node[xshift=4cm,yshift=-7.5cm,draw,fill=white,rectangle,minimum height=1.2cm,text width=1.5cm,align=center] (D)
  {$ y_t $};  

\path[->] (A) edge (C);
\draw [->] (B) to (C);
\draw [->] (C) to (D);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please always post compilable code as it makes things much easier than mere snippets.

Answer (score 4):

Give the label node a name with `label={[name=kalman]above:\textbf{Kalman filter}}`, and draw to `kalman` instead of `C`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,fill=white,ellipse,minimum height=5cm,minimum width=5cm,text width = 2cm,align=center,label=above:\textbf{State-space model}] (A)
  {Transition \\
  abc abc \\
  $ \downarrow $ \\
  Measurement\\
  $y_t  = \hat{t}$ };
\node[xshift=8cm,draw,fill=white,ellipse,minimum height=5cm,minimum width=5cm,text width=2cm,align=center,label=above:\textbf{Estimated data Empirical data}] (B)
  {$ y \rightarrow \emptyset $ \\
  \vspace{5mm}
  $ y_{t / t-1} \rightarrow y_t $};
\node[xshift=4cm,yshift=-5cm,draw,fill=white,ellipse,text width=4cm,align=center,label={[name=kalman]above:\textbf{Kalman filter}}] (C)
  {$ v_t = y_t - y_{t,t-1} $};
\node[xshift=4cm,yshift=-7.5cm,draw,fill=white,rectangle,minimum height=1.2cm,text width=1.5cm,align=center] (D)
  {$ y_t $};  

\draw [->] (A) to (kalman);
\draw [->] (B) to (kalman);
\draw [->] (C) to (D);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED ANSWER**: For some reason you seem not to like [Torbjørn's nice solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443371/121799), so here comes an alternative: use Torbjørn's nice solution along with `fit`. This has the advantage that the arrows point to the `C` node, not to the label, and gets rid of the big disadvantage of my previous proposal (see below) where one has to adjust distances by hand.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,fill=white,ellipse,minimum height=5cm,minimum width=5cm,text width = 2cm,align=center,label=above:\textbf{State-space model}] (A)
  {Transition \\
  abc abc \\
  $ \downarrow $ \\
  Measurement\\
  $y_t  = \hat{t}$ };
\node[xshift=8cm,draw,fill=white,ellipse,minimum height=5cm,minimum width=5cm,text width=2cm,align=center,label=above:\textbf{Estimated data Empirical data}] (B)
  {$ y \rightarrow \emptyset $ \\[5mm]
  $ y_{t / t-1} \rightarrow y_t $};
\node[xshift=4cm,yshift=-5cm,draw,fill=white,ellipse,text width=4cm,align=center,
label={[name=kalman,font=\bfseries]above:Kalman filter}] (C)
  {$ v_t = y_t - y_{t,t-1} $};
\node[xshift=4cm,yshift=-7.5cm,draw,fill=white,rectangle,minimum height=1.2cm,text width=1.5cm,align=center] (D)
  {$ y_t $};  
\node[fit=(C) (kalman)] (F){};

\draw[->] (A) to (F);
\draw[->] (B) to (F);
\draw [->] (C) to (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL PROPOSAL**: use `shorten`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,fill=white,ellipse,minimum height=5cm,minimum width=5cm,text width = 2cm,align=center,label=above:\textbf{State-space model}] (A)
  {Transition \\
  abc abc \\
  $ \downarrow $ \\
  Measurement\\
  $y_t  = \hat{t}$ };
\node[xshift=8cm,draw,fill=white,ellipse,minimum height=5cm,minimum width=5cm,text width=2cm,align=center,label=above:\textbf{Estimated data Empirical data}] (B)
  {$ y \rightarrow \emptyset $ \\[5mm]
  $ y_{t / t-1} \rightarrow y_t $};
\node[xshift=4cm,yshift=-5cm,draw,fill=white,ellipse,text width=4cm,align=center,label=above:\textbf{Kalman filter}] (C)
  {$ v_t = y_t - y_{t,t-1} $};
\node[xshift=4cm,yshift=-7.5cm,draw,fill=white,rectangle,minimum height=1.2cm,text width=1.5cm,align=center] (D)
  {$ y_t $};  

\draw[->,shorten >=6mm] (A) edge (C);
\draw[->,shorten >=6mm] (B) to (C);
\draw [->] (C) to (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The big disadvantage of this solution is that you have to put in the `6mm` by hand, the slight advantage is that the arrows point to the center of the `C` node, not to the center of the label.